# How do I have weblogic reload cached JSPs on restart

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

Our method of deploying a new version of an app for weblogic (11g) is to copy over top of the existing ear file and then stop and restart the weblogic server. We do a start/stop of weblogic rather than a redeployment, because of the known permgen issue (where eventually we will run out of perm gen and have to bounce the weblogic server).

However, this method of deploying has a drawback-- new JSP versions are not seen by weblogic. In order to fix this we have had to wipe out the contents of the tmp directory that maintain a cache of the compiled JSPs prior to restarting the server. Is there a setting that would tell weblogic to wipe the cache/reload/recompile JSPs when it starts back up?

Answer (score 6):

**Changing the JSP refresh timer**

A standard solution is to tell Weblogic to check JSP freshness more frequently by either setting the value in your `web.xml` or in your `weblogic.xml`.

In production mode, Weblogic won't check for new JSP versions (*default value: -1*) while it does each second in development mode (*default value: 1*).

The choice between modifying `web.xml` or `weblogic.xml` is up to you, regarding the application servers you target, being WebLogic only or not.

If you prefer to modify `web.xml`, then set a value for the context parameter `weblogic.jsp.pageCheckSeconds` as follows:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>weblogic.jsp.pageCheckSeconds</param-name>
  <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you prefer to modify `weblogic.xml`, then set a value for parameter `page-check-seconds` in the `jsp-descriptor` section. Here is the relevant excerpt from the documentation:

> Sets the interval, in seconds, at which WebLogic Server checks to see if JSP files have changed and need recompiling. Dependencies are also checked and recursively reloaded if changed.
>   The value -1 means never check the pages. This is the default value in a production environment.
>   The value 0 means always check the pages.
>   The value 1 means check the pages every second. This is the default value in a development environment.
>   In a production environment where changes to a JSP are rare, consider changing the value of  pageCheckSeconds to 60 or greater, according to your tuning requirements.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm#i1038490

**Forcing redeployment**

Restarting Weblogic server does not force it to redeploy a Web Application (especially in production mode).

*Solution*
Trigger explicitly the "redeploy" life-cycle operation using command line like this:

```
java -cp weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -redeploy [-remote -adminurl t3://hostname:hostport] -username login -password password -name webapp.name [-upload -source webapp.war]
```

- Note that `-redeploy` is WAYS much safer than `-update`, esp. with Weblogic <= 10.x
- Keep first block between [ ], only if the server is not local. Remove the [ ] in that case.
- Keep second block between [ ], if you want to combine the *WAR file* uploading in the same step, which is way simpler. Remove the [ ] in that case.

Comment: I have the same issue. The page-check-seconds works fine when modifying the deployed JSP files directly. In the scenario described by @BestPractices though, where the server is shutdown and then the files are deployed, weblogic does not seem to notice that all/some of the files have changed and uses the generated classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this you should first update your Module and then restart the server..this should fix your problem.

Although process mentioned by is always give 100% correctness. But you can try above mentioned steps.