# In Weblogic 10.3.5, is there any way to expire an html file from cache without going through a server restart

Tags: caching, weblogic, http-caching, peoplesoft

In Weblogic 10.3.5, is there any way to expire an html file from cache without going through a server restart.  I am supporting a server with frequent HTML changes and hoping to find a way not to restart the server each time the HTML is updated. Environment is supporting a PeopleSoft domain.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way indeed, the parameter "Resource Reload Check (in seconds)" which can be found on a web app setup is what you're looking for. I've setup this to 5(secondes) in order to have a periodic refresh on dynamic ressources generated by an application engine (an xml parsed by an xslt)

For some details here's doc of 12.1.2  but I confirm it exists also on 10.3.4 (so on your version too) : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLACH/pagehelp/J2EEwebappwebappconfigurationtitle.html

Comment: You may also be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358081/how-do-i-have-weblogic-reload-cached-jsps-on-restart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476461/how-do-i-refresh-jsps-on-weblogic

Comment: <resource-reload-check-secs>1</resource-reload-check-secs> worked nicely in weblogic.xml.  Thanks a lot.
Is there any performance impact this change would cause.  Site is mostly based on dynamically created pages.  Very few static content.