# How to disable text/html from being cached in Weblogic 12?

Tags: html, caching, weblogic

I have a page that is being cached, so when I log out it's reloaded from the disk cache without ever hitting the server. If I disable the cache via the browser's network inspector, it reloads the page correctly by requesting the page from the server, which then redirects to a login screen. That solution only works in development.

Is there a good way via either the web.xml or the weblogic.xml to disable caching of the html page itself?

- I've looked at setting the `resource-reload-check-secs` value to 0
  and 1 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912573/in-weblogic-10-3-5-is-there-any-way-to-expire-an-html-file-from-cache-without-g), but this does not work for me since the
  resources have not changed.
- I've also seen Weblogic's cache filter, [but it's deprecated.](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/cache/filter/package-summary.html)

Comment: This is a browser caching issue, not a server caching issue. You can use these meta to prevent browsers from caching your pages : 
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate"> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">`

Comment: Whatever I do with these tags I can't prevent FireFox 52 (current target) from caching them. It works fine in Chrome.