# wldeploy - partial redeploy of remote application

Tags: jsp, weblogic, redeploy

I have an exploded EAR deployed on remote Weblogic Server with nostage="false" mode. The EAR is very large so the full undeploy / deploy is very slow each time.

If I modify a JSP under "stage" folder I see immediately changes in web-app.

If I add a JSP under "stage" folder I cannot see the news jsp in web-app.

Is possible a partial remote redeploy of the jsps (and only the jsps) ?
I tried something like that

```
<target name="fastdeploy" >
<wldeploy action="redeploy" verbose="true" debug="true"   
name="${earNameTarget}"
user="${wls.username}" password="${wls.password}" 
adminurl="t3://${wls.host}:${wls.port}" targets="${deployTarget}" 
usenonexclusivelock="true"
deltaFiles="LOCAL PATH OF THE JSPS">
<files dir="REMOTE PATH OF THE JSPS">
includes="*.*" />
</wldeploy>
</target>
```

but I got

> [DeploymentService:290066]Error occurred while downloading files from
>   Administration Server for deployment request"1,439,276,275,680".
>   Underlying error is: "null"   at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.datatransferhandlers.HttpDataTransferHandler.getDataAsStream(HttpDataTransferHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.datatransferhandlers.DataHandlerManager$RemoteDataTransferHandler.getDataAsStream(DataHandlerManager.java:153)

Any suggest?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358081/how-do-i-have-weblogic-reload-cached-jsps-on-restart and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476461/how-do-i-refresh-jsps-on-weblogic and http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=578

Comment: Yes I tried all of them, but none work. But I am not sure that the syntax of wldeploy written above is correct.